# How can I swap Characters in a string

Tags: java, string

I wrote this bit of code to swap characters in a word
but for some reason its not swapping the first Character, any help will be appreciated.

```
public class StringWorker{
    public static void main (String[]arg$){

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter a word: ");
        String str = in.nextLine();

        char[] newCh = str.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
        int length= str.length()-1;
        char temp;

        for (int i=0; i<length; i++){

                temp = newCh[i];    
                newCh[i] = newCh[i++];
                newCh[i++] = temp;


        }
        String revamped = String.valueOf(newCh);
        System.out.println(revamped);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're calling `i++` too often.

Comment: you need to swap each two characters of the word, right?

Comment: Style note: consider following the Java class naming convention of beginning the class name with an uppercase character. Which means swapping stringWorker with StringWorker.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change:

```
for (int i=0; i<length; i++){                   
    temp = newCh[i];    
    newCh[i] = newCh[i++];
    newCh[i++] = temp;
```

to:

```
for (int i=0; i<length - 1; i++){   
    temp = newCh[i];    
    newCh[i] = newCh[i+1];
    newCh[i+1] = temp;
}
```

`i++` is incrementing `i` (like `i = i + 1`), so by the time you get through the first iteration of the loop, `i` is already 2.

Additional: This is the first thing that leapt out at me, but I'm curious as to your definition of "swap". This little fix will just result in the first character being moved all the way to the end e.g. "swap" will become "waps".

Comment: would this not cause an error when it reaches the last character. I was using 'swap' rather loosely

Comment: If only the first and the last character needs to be swapped wouldn't the following the better solution, compared to a loop? `new StringBuilder(str.substring(1)).append(str.charAt(0))`.

Comment: @Ambassador - Yup, I've amended the change. I only had a couple of mins free earlier so I forgot to put that in.

Comment: @SubOptimal - That's another way, but I was just looking to fix the existing code in order to explain the root cause of the problem :-)